# bootstrap-datepicker in dd/mm/yyyy - selected date is displayed as mm/dd/yyyy after minDate or maxDate is set

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am dynamically creating html and prepopulating some tabs. This includes a Start and End date on each tab using bootstrap-datepicker as dd/mm/yyyy. When I change a Start date the minDate, in the End Date, is set. However, when I select a new End Date it is displayed as mm/dd/yyyy. The same applies if I select the End Date first to the Start Date (maxDate is set and when I select a new Start Date it is displayed as mm/dd/yyyy).

I create my html (this is on one or more tabs):

```
    //Start Date
    contents += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
    contents += '<div class="form-group">';
    contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="startDate0a">Start Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
    contents += '<div class="input-group date datepicker1" id="datepicker1">';
    contents += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate0a" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" value="" required>';
    contents += '<span class="input-group-addon">';
    contents += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
    contents += '</span>';
    contents += '</div>';
    contents += '</div>';
    contents += '</div>';
    //End Date
    contents += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
    contents += '<div class="form-group">';
    contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="endDate0a">End Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
    contents += '<div class="input-group date datepicker2" id="datepicker2">';
    contents += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate0a" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date" value="" required>';
    contents += '<span class="input-group-addon">';
    contents += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
    contents += '</span>';
    contents += '</div>';
    contents += '</div>';
    contents += '</div>';
    contents += '</div>';
```

I then catch the change of date and set the max or min date:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.datepicker1' , function () {
        var date1ID = $(this).attr('id')
        var date2ID =  $(this).attr('id').replace("datepicker1", "datepicker2");
        $('#'+date1ID).datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
                var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                $('#'+date2ID).datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);//set min date
        }).datepicker("show");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.datepicker2', function () {
        var date2ID = $(this).attr('id')
        var date1ID =  $(this).attr('id').replace("datepicker2", "datepicker1");
        $('#'+date2ID).datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
                var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                $('#'+date1ID).datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);//sets max date
        }).datepicker("show");
    });
```

My cdn is:

```
        <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
```

I have tried the solution at:

[datepicker, minDate, maxDate + dateformat issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875535/datepicker-mindate-maxdate-dateformat-issue)

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
});
```

i.e.,

```
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker1' , function () {
    var date1ID = $(this).attr('id')
    var date2ID =  $(this).attr('id').replace("datepicker1", "datepicker2");
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    });
    $('#'+date1ID).datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            });
            var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#'+date2ID).datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);//set min date
    }).datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Check the browser console for javascript errors. I believe that the trailing comma in both `setDefaults` function calls: `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', <= HERE` is causing trouble.

Comment: Hi Paul, while not necessary when there is not another default, the comma does not cause an error and there is no difference when the comma is removed. Thank you :-)

Comment: I see. I guess the bootstrap framework handles that better than others that I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move whole `datepicker` code outside `click` event . Then , inside `on('changeDate', function(selected) {` get the input of next or prev i.e : `endDate` or `startDate` and then using that id set max and min date for other input.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var contents = ""
//Start Date
contents += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
contents += '<div class="form-group">';
contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="startDate0a">Start Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
contents += '<div class="input-group date datepicker1" id="datepicker1">';
contents += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate0a" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" value="" required>';
contents += '<span class="input-group-addon">';
contents += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
contents += '</span>';
contents += '</div>';
contents += '</div>';
contents += '</div>';
//End Date
contents += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
contents += '<div class="form-group">';
contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="endDate0a">End Date<span class="req"> *</span></label>';
contents += '<div class="input-group date datepicker2" id="datepicker2">';
contents += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate0a" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date" value="" required>';
contents += '<span class="input-group-addon">';
contents += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
contents += '</span>';
contents += '</div>';
contents += '</div>';
contents += '</div>';
contents += '</div>';

$("div.rows").html(contents)
//for date picker1
$(".datepicker1 input").datepicker({
  showOn: "both",
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  var date2ID = $(this).closest(".col-lg-6").next().find("input").attr("id") //get id of input..next to this
  $('#' + date2ID).datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
})
//for date picker2
$(".datepicker2 input").datepicker({
  showOn: "both",
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  var date1ID = $(this).closest(".col-lg-6").prev().find("input").attr("id") //get input prev to this..
  var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  $('#' + date1ID).datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<div class="rows"></div>
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much.